# Force set Landscape orientation is not working in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I have the following code

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1004, 768.0f);
    // self.view.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This code will work fine for force setting landscape orientation

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I am using the following code in viewdidload.This code is working fine in test app but in my mainapp.

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
    {
        objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:),UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    }
}
```

It is working fine if i write test application
But in my Mainapp it is not working.I have xib in my Mainapp

Comment: @Fogmeister.. I edited please look at the question.

Comment: Are you only using landscape orientation for the entire app? Or are you using some landscape and some portrait?

Comment: @Fogmeister For entire app all orientation are supported.But for print view controller I need to force set landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure You have set Landscape mode for your Mainapp Application,

[image]

Edit

Than use Following method in Printview page ios5 and 6

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation)) {
        return  YES;
    }
    return NO;

}
```

for ios 7

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
        return  YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: I want my app to support all orientations.Only for particular controller (Print view) I need to force view to Landscape

Answer (score 0):

In your project setting you need to check all the orientations that should be available in your app (even if you only use it once).

Then on your top most level object, usually a (Custom)UITabBar or (Custom)UINavigationBar, you have to implement some logic with these orientation methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

It think its best if you have a look for more detailed tutorials or answers on rotation.

[iOS6+ Rotation](http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-development/iphone/ios-6-rotation-solution/)

I don't know if your project also supports iOS5, but that version handles rotation different.

Answer (score 0):

First you will set this from .xib 
[image]

and then write this methods for that particular  view

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

and for another classes/views write Orientation for all.

NOTE:- you need to write these methods in all classes.

Comment: @virantporwal.. If u can see i am able torotate to landscape.but it should fix to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following code in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientaiton = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    NSLog(@"orientation %d",orientaiton);


    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientaiton)){
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
        {
            if(orientaiton == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
                objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
            else if (orientaiton == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
                objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
        }
    }
}
```

I can rotate to landscape.but problem is view is rotating to portrait and then returning to landscape.But I don't want that.I want to fix the view to landscape.

Comment: view -> rotating to portrait -> rotating to landscape.this is the scenario.But I want view-> always landscape.->if user tries to rotate also it should not show up portrait.still I am facing that problem.can anybody give me solution.please.